# Access value of function attribute in python

Tags: python

Suppose I have a function -

```
def foo(x,y):  
    pass  
a = foo(5,6)
```

How do I access the values 5 and 6 from `a`?

Comment: You can't.  `x` and `y` are temporary variables inside of `foo()`.

Comment: What? What do are you trying to do?

Comment: unless you save those values before the function call or the function save them in a global variable or return them, you can't...

Comment: Why not make them variables beforehand `x,y=5,6`, then call foo(x,y), you'll always have them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the code you have shown us, you cannot -- `5` and `6` were passed in to `foo`, you didn't keep a copy of them, `foo` didn't keep a copy of them, so they are gone.

So, as the above paragraph hinted, somebody has to keep a copy of those arguments if you want to do something else with them later, and while it is possible to have a function do so, that's not really what they are intended for.  So your easy options are:

- make `foo` a class that saves the arguments it was called with (which is still highly unusual), or
- save the arguments yourself  (`arg1, arg2 = 5, 6` for example)

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You'd need to use an object.